# Android: Showing Action Bar menu items depending on ViewPager

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-viewpager

I am having trouble getting the following piece of code to work out.  I have a `viewpager` with 3 fragments, and I want a search icon to only show up on one.  I started off trying to add the search function by the fragment, but the rendering of the menu item was slow when swiping to that page.  I am now on the part to add the search icon to the activity, and then just hide or show depending on which `viewpager` page is active, but the following is not working:

```
public class MyApp extends FragmentActivity implements 
   FragmentTeams.FragmentNotification,ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener, 
      OnNavigationListener{

  ...

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);

    menuSearch = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search);
    mSearchView = new SearchView(this);
    menuSearch.setActionView(mSearchView);
    menuSearch.setVisible(false);
    return true;
}

 @Override
public void onPageSelected(int pageNum) {

if(pageNum== 1){     
    ActionBar actionBar = MyApp.this.getActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);     
        menuSearch.setVisible(true);
        invalidateOptionsMenu();

}else{           
    ActionBar actionBar = MyApp.this.getActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);  
        menuSearch.setVisible(false);
        invalidateOptionsMenu();
    }
}
```

While the above does (appear to) create and hide the icon at `onCreateOptionsMenu`, it is not reenabled when moving to

```
 pageNum ==1
```

Can anyone give me some insight as to why this may be happening?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`invalidateOptionsMenu` make the system calls the method `onPrepareOptionsMenu`, so you can override this method as follows:

```
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
      int pageNum = getCurrentPage();
      if (pageNum == 1) {
         menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search).setVisible(true);

      }
      else {
         menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search).setVisible(false);
      }
   }

public void onPageSelected(int pageNum) {
    invalidateOptionsMenu();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! This does work correctly.  However, there is still a slight delay from the time I swipe to a page and the rendering of the menu items.  I am going to follow up by studying the stock Google apps, as it seems they render instantly.

Comment: If you use support library then its `supportInvalidateOptionsMenu()`

Comment: Well I am not able to find the getCurrentPage() method, is it userdefined or of Android itself?

Answer (score 4):

You can implement onCreateOptionsMenu() in your Fragment and set 'setHasOptionsMenu(true)' for the fragment

Comment: I did this and it works on some devices; but on other devices it only works when you go to the next page and go back (it does not work the first time)

Comment: That is weird...feels like bugs in the specific implementation of those devices...damn manufacturers...

Answer (score 0):

a possible solution for this problem would be inflating your custom menu inside the activity hosts your ViewPager and getting a menu reference as below:

```
 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
     getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.custom_menu, menu);
     customMenu = menu;
     return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
 }
```

after that you can easily hide/show the menu's items without any delay inside onPageSelected method as below:

```
 @Override
 public void onPageSelected(int position) {
  switch (position) {
        case 0: { 
           customMenu.getItem(0).setVisible(false);
           break;
        }
       case 1: { 
           customMenu.getItem(0).setVisible(true);
             break;
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

I used Nermeen's answer and managed to get it without any delay.

I don't inflate anything in `onCreateOptionsMenu`, but use it to get a reference to the menu:

```
 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
     customMenu = menu;
     return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
 }
```

Then, in `onPrepareOptionsMenu()`, I call the viewpager `getCurrentItem()` (should be something like `viewPager.getCurrentItem()`), call `invalidateOptionsMenu()` and inflate whatever menu I want in that page using the customMenu reference I created in `onCreateOptionsMenu()`.